r dataframe and matrix result in different rownames when using rbind
Method 1:
df1<-data.frame(A=1:5,B=2:6)
df2<-data.frame(A=1:5,B=2:6)
df3<-rbind(df1,df2)
row.names(df3)
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"

Method 2:
df1<-data.frame(matrix(data = c(1:5,2:6),
                       nrow = 5,
                       dimnames = list(c(1:5),c("A","B"))))
df2<-data.frame(matrix(data = c(1:5,2:6),
                       nrow = 5,
                       dimnames = list(c(1:5),c("A","B"))))
df3<-rbind(df1,df2)
row.names(df3)
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "11" "21" "31" "41" "51"

I understand that the rownames should be unique values, I would like to known why Mehtod1 and Method 2 generate different resutls in the rownames?

In Method 1, the row names are integers
df1 <- data.frame(A=1:5,B=2:6)
df2 <- data.frame(A=1:5,B=2:6)

dput(df1)
structure(list(A = 1:5, B = 2:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))

# or
attr(df1, "row.names")
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

and they stay integers after rbind
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)

dput(df3)
structure(list(A = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
    B = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA,
-10L), class = "data.frame")

In Method 2, the row names are strings
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(data = c(1:5,2:6),
                         nrow = 5,
                         dimnames = list(c(1:5),c("A","B"))))
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(data = c(1:5,2:6),
                         nrow = 5,
                         dimnames = list(c(1:5),c("A","B"))))

dput(df1)
structure(list(A = 1:5, B = 2:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4", "5"))

# or
attr(df1, "row.names")
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"

and they also remain the original class, strings (character), after rbind
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)

dput(df3)
structure(list(A = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
    B = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4", "5", "11", "21", "31", "41", "51"), class = "data.frame")

Strings can't be enumerated so they are made unique by adding an index to the string.
You can equalize the two by adding row.names=NULL when creating the data frame from a matrix with given row names.
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(data = c(1:5,2:6),
                         nrow = 5,
                         dimnames = list(c(1:5),c("A","B"))), row.names=NULL)

dput(df1)
structure(list(A = 1:5, B = 2:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))


Nice catch and excellent explanations, +1!

Is there a deeper reason why the two methods take different approaches in assigning row names, i.e. why method 1 is using integers and method 2 is using strings?

@deschen In the second the row names ultimately come from matrix's argument dimnames which is specific to matrix and if you don't use NULL for the dimension it seems to use characters per default.

Interesting. Thanks!

I think @Andre Wildberg has already made an elaborated explanation about "Why the second method is not working the same as the first one".

Below is just a simple workaround using list2DF to filter out the original row.name information
> rbind(list2DF(df1), list2DF(df2))
   A B
1  1 2
2  2 3
3  3 4
4  4 5
5  5 6
6  1 2
7  2 3
8  3 4
9  4 5
10 5 6

or call rbind like below
> do.call(rbind, list(df1, df2, make.row.names = FALSE))
   A B
1  1 2
2  2 3
3  3 4
4  4 5
5  5 6
6  1 2
7  2 3
8  3 4
9  4 5
10 5 6


You can use .row_names_info to get "information on the internal form of the row names for a data frame". When its type argument is 1 (default), it returns the number of rows "with a negative sign for ‘automatic’ row names", as in your first example. For user-generated names it returns a positive number, like in your second example.
Although the printed row names of the original data frames are identical, the differing internal representation of "automatic" and user-defined row names are treated differently when row binded.
# automatic row names
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 2:6)
df2 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 2:6)

df1_2 <- rbind(df1, df2)

# row names provided by user
df3 <- data.frame(matrix(data = c(1:5,2:6),
                       nrow = 5,
                       dimnames = list(1:5, c("A","B"))))
df4 <- data.frame(matrix(data = c(1:5,2:6),
                       nrow = 5,
                       dimnames = list(1:5, c("A","B"))))

df3_4 <- rbind(df3, df4)

.row_names_info(df1)
# [1] -5

.row_names_info(df2)
# [1] -5

.row_names_info(df1_2)
# [1] -10

.row_names_info(df3)
# [1] 5

.row_names_info(df4)
# [1] 5

.row_names_info(df3_4)
# [1] 10

Another example with no row names in the matrix call, which results in automatic row names in the data.frame call; hence .row_names_info results in a negative number:
df3 <- data.frame(matrix(data = c(1:5,2:6),
                       nrow = 5,
                       dimnames = list(NULL, c("A","B"))))
df4 <- data.frame(matrix(data = c(1:5,2:6),
                       nrow = 5,
                       dimnames = list(NULL, c("A","B"))))

df3_4 <- rbind(df3, df4)

.row_names_info(df3_4)
# [1] -10


